# How to convert an input to discord.user object?

Tags: python, discord.py

There's my code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def Espulsione(ctx, member:discord.user = None, motivo = None):
    await ctx.send(f'I kicked {member.mention}')
```

Until yesterday, I've never had problems with that kind of commands, but now it doesn't work.

The problem is with converting the input string member into a discord.user object.

This is the raised error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "discord.user" failed for parameter "member".
```

If it's usefull, you can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/Discord.py/blob/dafd7716bbfad884594bcb33f398e5970280e7bd/BOT%20Lillo.py#L98), to understand better where the problem might be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with capital, “discord.User”

Comment: Yes, sorry, I noticed the capital right now, so I opened that page to close the question.
I don't see the check mark 'cause your answer is just a comment... I'll leave the question like how it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) should start with capital, since it's the name of a class:

```py
@Bot.command()
async def Espulsione(ctx, member: discord.User=None, motivo=None):
```

Comment: FYI, using `discord.Member` (or a converter) is better since it will allow for guild-specific actions.